# "margin: 0" não zera totalmente

Tags: css

Tenho um problema e, ainda que "meio resolvido" (gambiarra), eu gostaria de saber o que o causa.

Tenho uma `ul` com `white-space: nowrap;` e as `li`'s dela em `display: inline-block;`

O problema é que ainda fica um espaçamento entre os `li`'s, mesmo tendo o reset de `margin: 0;`, e quando eu seto as margens delas para -2px, fica normal. Eu gostaria de saber o que causa isso. Segue abaixo o código de exemplo

```css
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}

.teste {
      margin: 20px auto;
      white-space: nowrap;
      list-style: none;
      width: 150px;
      height: 90px;
      background: blue;
}

.teste>* {
      width: 100%;
      height: 90px;
      background: green;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
}

/* AQUI, QUANDO EU SETO margin: -2px;  AS LI's SE JUNTAM */

.dois>* {
       margin: -2px;
}
```

```html
 <ul class="teste" >
    <li> Li 1 </li>
    <li> Li 2 </li>
    <li> Li 3 </li>
 </ul>
 
  <ul class="teste dois" >
    <li> Li 1 </li>
    <li> Li 2 </li>
    <li> Li 3 </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Podes também visitar [este artigo](https://goo.gl/h8TcYw) que criei para ler mais e ver outros hacks e soluções sobre este tópico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando tens elementos com `inline-block` os espaços entre o HTML criam esse afastamento. Aparentemente não tens espaços mas uma quebra de linha é considerado um espaço. Se tiveres o HTML todo na mesma linha, ou pelo menos não houver espaco/quebra de linha entre o fecho de uma tag e a abertura da próxima, então vai funcionar.

Outra solução é como fizeste, usando `margin` negativa.

```css
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}

.teste {
      margin: 20px auto;
      white-space: nowrap;
      list-style: none;
      width: 150px;
      height: 90px;
      background: blue;
}

.teste>* {
      width: 100%;
      height: 90px;
      background: green;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="teste" >
    <li> Li 1 </li><li> Li 2 </li><li> Li 3 </li>
 </ul>
 
  <ul class="teste dois" >
    <li> Li 1 </li><li> Li 2 </li><li> Li 3 </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Entendi. Nunca pensaria nisso; eu achava que o navegador ignorava as quebras (rsrs). Valeu!